# two fragments in an activity.xml are not sharing width of the screen

Tags: android

I've two fragments inside an activity.xml but the width is not 50% for each.

I believe following are the properties to make them work, please advise if not.

```
layout_weight="1"

layout_width="0dp"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_fragment" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FormFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ListFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/form_fragment" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout rather than a ConstraintLayout.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight

Or use `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain

Answer (score 0):

The parent layout for these fragments is ConstraintLayout and layoutWeight attribute does not work with that. if you want to divide the layout using this attribute the only thing you need to do is to change constraintLayout to LinearLayout.